# How to generate / adding new page using command in Ionic-react

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

```
ionic g page topic
```

This command gives following error

> [ERROR] Cannot perform generate for React projects.
>
> Since you're using the React project type, this command won't work.
>   The Ionic CLI doesn't know how to generate framework components for
>   React projects.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear, the Ionic cli doesn't support generating new pages for a project that uses React. That means you'll have to create the files manually.